# Issues with animation in android

Tags: android, animation

My project is a static android app that has been completed now, the user requires an animation for all button clicks in home page. I built a separate project and completed the animation dynamically.

The problem is:

```
 1) The animation works alternatively in sample project. ie When the project is first activated the animation doesn't work and when its closed and restarted the animation works.
 2) This animation on being added to the main project fails altogether. As in the animation doesn't work but the intent works and the app moves to next activity without issues.(there is a time delay. before the activity moves to next )
```

my question is that

```
 1) why is animation not working properly?
 2) why does same code not produce any animation in main project?
```

my code is as follows..

```
 public class Button_Anime extends Activity{
 private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 550;
 AnimationDrawable animate= new AnimationDrawable();
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  //String values = intent.getStringExtra("Value");

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_about);
  RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayButtonAnime);
  ImageView loading =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVArcRail_2);

  final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inSampleSize = 32;
  options.inPurgeable = true;
  options.inScaled = true;
  Bitmap b;
  Drawable d;

  int i =50;
  b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab1, options);
  d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b);   
  animate.addFrame(d, i);
  b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab2, options);
  d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
  animate.addFrame(d, i);
  b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab3, options);
  d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
  animate.addFrame(d, i);
  b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab4, options);
  d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
  animate.addFrame(d, i);
  b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab5, options);
  d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
  animate.addFrame(d, i);
  b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab6, options);
  d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
  animate.addFrame(d, i);
  b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab7, options);
  d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
  animate.addFrame(d, i);
  b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab8, options);
  d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
  animate.addFrame(d, i);
  b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab9, options);
  d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
  animate.addFrame(d, i);
  b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab10, options);
  d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
  animate.addFrame(d, i);

  loading.setBackgroundDrawable(animate);
  loading.post(new Refiney());
  System.gc();
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  TimerTask timertask = new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Intent intent = new Intent(Button_Anime.this, Home.class); 
   startActivity(intent);
   }
 };
 timer.schedule(timertask, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
 Button_Anime.this.finish();
 //main(values);        
 }

 class Refiney implements Runnable {

 public void run() {
 animate.start();   
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: so this animation work in onresume?? but not when first time create?

Comment: yes pls note the fact that this happens only when the animation is a stand alone project when included in main project none of the animation works.. and yes i did built the project b4 running it.. @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: @AlexLockwood pls take a look at this..